# Guest WI-FI implementation - HP switch (comware) and Brocade/Motorola AP 7131

Tags: switch, wireless, vlan, ieee-802.11, hp-procurve

I have been asked to add a guest Wi-Fi network to our existing Wi-Fi network.

We have an HP switch (Comware) v1910 and Brocade/Motorola AP 7131.

We have created an untrusted interface on the firewall to allow guest users.

The firewall will provide DHCP in the range 192.168.100.0/24 for users on the guest Wi-Fi.

I would like to know if this can be implemented and if so how one would go about doing this?

I am not sure how one would implement a VLAN and get this working.

Any help or advice will be appreciated.

Comment: its a bit confusing on exactly what you want? do you want to integrate this to your network or by pass the network straight out to the web? sadly these access points are the bane of my life. I have more knowledge of these APs then any other AP

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can:

The configuration must be on this way:

User-------AP-------------Switch---------------Firewall(DHCP)

```
           VLAN_guest      VLAN_guest
```

The port of the switch connected to the firewall and the AP must be located on the same VLAN like "Access Ports".

You must configure your AP on the way that be a bridge between your LAN and wifi users, on the way to provide the IP address gives by your Firewall and not by your AP.

Comment: ok - I assume you need to untagged ports AP and FW is connected to and one problem is those who are authenticated with radius will get it IP from DHCP server on VlAN 1. and no routing possible between guest vlan to other vlan. how to ensure that I am getting correct IP for guest and registered users?

Answer (score 0):

The AP has a router baked in which can probably hand out it's own addresses (internal DHCP server).  Just create an OUTSIDE VLAN on your switch and plug the outside address of your firewall into it and the AP into it.  If inside users want internal access they can VPN in via your firewall.  That's the easy way.

If you want the AP to talk inside and outside WLAN's (SSID's) that can be done but requires a little more configuration.  You need a trunk link between the AP and switch and between the firewall and switch to carry frames from both WLANs to the firewall.  This will mean configuring your inside firewall port as a trunk as well.